# The fun in numbers

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

A friend of mine gave me this riddle.

Find the next number of the sequence:

293, 313, 331, ...

Let's see who can do better than I did.

Hint:

There is a new number:

> 263, 293, 313, 331, ...

Comment: Did your friend give any additional numbers or clues? With three numbers there will be many sequences that may fit, but not be the intended answer. for example: rot13(svefg nqq gjragl, gura nqq rvtugrra, nqq fvkgrra naq fb ba)

Comment: Yes, but he gave me the previous number' not the next one. I will edit the question and add the new number.

Comment: does this is related to [10-happy-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is:

> A list of happy prime numbers

So a longer list includes:

> 7, 13, 19, 23, 31, 79, 97, 103, 109, 139, 167, 193, 239, **263, 293, 313, 331,** 367, 379, 383, 397, 409, 487.

Comment: @omri klein Make sure you not to tell your friend that you had help from a community with solving it

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of prime numbers follows the pattern below

›! The next number is 337.

263  4x+3

293  4x+1

313  4x+1

331  4x+3

337  4x+1

Comment: Nice idea, but check out the last answer, it's the right answer.

Comment: From the number you gave I drew the conclusion one prime 4x+3  two primes 4x+1 one prime 4x+3 and two primes 4x+1.